# Flatten A Collection With Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

What's the best way to flatten a query that produces a collection that looks like this?

[image]

Instead of two rows for ClaimType Target, I want to produce a linq query or expression that has one row for ClaimType Target with both values of Tools and Compass in the same column.

```
ClaimType | ClaimValue
Target    | Tools;Compass
```

Any ideas, I'm having a total brain cloud on this!

Comment: I'm not sure how Linq to SQL will behave with joining strings, but try to broup by `ClaimType` and then select `String.Join(";", g.Select(x => x.ClaimType))`

Comment: The first thing I tried was a group by but that reduced the row set to 2, removing the last row containing claim value of Compass from the query :(

Comment: GroupBy does not remove any row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do this:

```
var claims = new []
{
    new { ClaimType = "Redirect Url", ClaimValue = "https://www.thing.com/" },
    new { ClaimType = "Target", ClaimValue = "Tools" },
    new { ClaimType = "Target", ClaimValue = "Compass" },
};

var query =
    from claim in claims
    group claim by claim.ClaimType into claim_groups
    select new
    {
        ClaimType = claim_groups.Key,
        ClaimValues = String.Join(";", claim_groups.Select(x => x.ClaimValue)),
    };
```

That will give you this:

[image: query]

Comment: NICE! Thanks, that is almost exaclty what I came up with BUT I was doing it in two queries instead of one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the table I have created list of objects to simulate your data I hope this might help

```C#
 List<item> items = new List<item>();

            items.Add(new item { id = 1, name = "A", CliamId = "6", ClaimValue = "Any" });
            items.Add(new item { id = 1, name = "Target", CliamId = "8", ClaimValue = "Tools" });
            items.Add(new item { id = 1, name = "Target", CliamId = "9", ClaimValue = "Compass" });


            var query = from i in items
                        group i by i.name
                        into g
                        select g;

            foreach(var item in query)
            {
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", item.Key));
                foreach(var row in item)
                {
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ",row.ClaimValue));

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        // end of the class
    }

    class item
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string CliamId { get; set; }
        public string ClaimValue { get; set; }
        // end of the calss
    }
```

The Result :

[image]

Comment: That's a perfect mock up. Thanks @Cyber Progs